# Is runat=server the correct way of running?

Tags: asp.net

I am a newcomer developer to ASP.NET.

I wonder that is running forms on server (namely runat=server) the right way of coding ? I feel that all of scripts, forms etc. must run on client side because server side runnings may cause bottleneck on server side.
So what kind of advantages/ disadvantages 
-running on server side
-running on client side ?

Comment: I'm voting to close since this question is too broad and opinion based. Because there are many possible answers and could heavily depend on your needs etc. SO is meant for specific programming questions.

Comment: You' re right. I searched on internet but I can not obtain any explanatory text and EXACTLY answer to my question.

Comment: But if you are new to programming I would recommend MVC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that `runat=server` means that ASP.Net does some processing on the server side.

This processing means that

- You have an object model you can use in your code, to access properties of your controls and event handlers (such as an OnClick for the various Buttons)
- The (possibly complicated - see grids) HTML is generated to be sent to the client (=browser)

The real form/script etc does run on the client. Validations run *both* client-side and server-side.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link will give you a good understanding of the difference. [difference between server and client controls](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/choose-between-server-and-client-controls/) There are plenty of explanations out there if you just Google